# Auto margin for input float left

Tags: input, width, margin, fill

```
<div style="width:500px">
<input type="text"><input type="text"><input type="text">
</div>
```

Inputs have width 31% and i will, that they fill the parent div in 100%. Auto margin for first two inputs. Like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see below code.

```
<div class="container">
<input type="text"><input type="text"><input type="text">
</div>

<style type="text/css">
.container {width:500px;}
.container input {width:30%;}
.container input:first-child {margin-right:5%;}
.container input:last-child {margin-left:5%;}
</style>
```

Comment: I've tried this, but it's not working. In one browser it's ok, but in another the last input landed under the others.

I need something that will set auto margins.

Or something like this, I'll set margin for first two inputs for example 10px and the width of all inputs will be auto.

Comment: can you please specify in which browser this is working and in which browser this is not working and please do not forgot write browser version also.